# How can I let users update the data in database through HTML in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

what I want do make is that

1. show the existing data in the database to a user through HTML page.
2. let a user update the existing data if he wants to do.

Promblem 1>
the problem is that,when running my code, a user input the new data and clicked 'update' button, but the update did not work.

Problem 2>
I set memo field in model like this :
memo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
However,after running the code, it just showed only one character of long characters in HTML.

Please refer to the below codes and result image.

<models.py>

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.memo} | {self.user_input} "
```

<forms.py>

```
from django import forms 
from report.models import Upload, Memo

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Upload
        fields=('upload_file',)
        
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    memo = forms.CharField()
    user_input = forms.IntegerField()
```

<views.py>

```
def input(request):
    items = Memo.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the item instance based on the memo from the form
            memo = form.cleaned_data['memo']
            item = Memo.objects.get(memo=memo)

            # Update the item with the new data from the form
            item.memo = form.cleaned_data['memo']
            item.user_input = form.cleaned_data['user_input']

            # Update other fields as needed

            item.save()
            return redirect('report/success.html')  # Redirect to the table display page after updating

    else:
        form = InputForm()

    return render(request, 'report/input.html', {'items': items, 'form': form})
```

<input.html>

```
<!-- update_table_template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Table Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Table Data</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>적요</th>
            <th>구분</th>
            <th>변경사항</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.memo }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user_input }}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="memo" value="{{ item.memo }}">
                    <input type="text" name="user_input" value="{{ item.user_input }}">
                    <!-- Add other fields as needed -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I really appreciate for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Your **InputForm** has `user_input = forms.IntegerField()` which is asking for an integer, but it looks like you are trying to enter a string, thus the form is invalid.

Comment: `Memo.objects.get(memo=memo)` this does not make sense. Instead, you should provide record id from the form to the view and locate `Memo` item with that id to update.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's a complete response that incorporates all your notes:

---

There are several problems you're facing:

1. Updates to the data are not working.
2. The `memo` field shows only one character in HTML, even though it should allow up to 100 characters.
3. You're using an `IntegerField` for the `user_input` field in the form, which should probably be a `CharField`.
4. You're using a regular `Form` where a `ModelForm` could simplify your code.

Here are solutions for these issues:

Solution 1:

Include the ID of each `Memo` instance in a hidden field within the form. This way, when the form is submitted, you know exactly which object in the database you need to update.

Modify your template as follows:

```html
<!-- update_table_template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Table Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Table Data</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>적요</th>
            <th>구분</th>
            <th>변경사항</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.memo }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user_input }}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <!-- The hidden input field -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ item.id }}">
                    <input type="text" name="memo" value="{{ item.memo }}">
                    <input type="text" name="user_input" value="{{ item.user_input }}">
                    <!-- Add other fields as needed -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Adjust your view to use this ID when fetching the object from the database:

```py
def input(request):
    items = Memo.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MemoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the ID from the form data
            item_id = request.POST.get('id')

            # Fetch the item by ID
            item = Memo.objects.get(id=item_id)

            # Update the item with the new data from the form
            item.memo = form.cleaned_data['memo']
            item.user_input = form.cleaned_data['user_input']

            # Update other fields as needed

            item.save()
            return redirect('success')  # Redirect to a URL pattern named 'success'

    else:
        form = MemoForm()

    return render(request, 'report/input.html', {'items': items, 'form': form})
```

Solution 2:

1. Open Django admin or get memo item from console, and check the real value in the DB.
2. Check the raw HTML in the browser, maybe characters hidden by CSS or outside the view.

Solution 3:

Change `user_input` to a `CharField` in your form, and in your model if necessary:

```py
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    memo = forms.CharField()
    user_input = forms.CharField()
```

Solution 4:

Use a `ModelForm` to simplify your form handling:

```py
from django import forms 
from .models import Memo

class MemoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Memo
        fields = ['memo', 'user_input']
```

And adjust your view to use this new `ModelForm`:

```py
def input(request):
    items = Memo.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MemoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the ID from the form data
            item_id = request.POST.get('id')

            # Fetch the item by ID
            item = Memo.objects.get(id=item_id)

            # Update the item with the new data from the form
            item.memo = form.cleaned_data['memo']
            item.user_input = form.cleaned_data['user_input']

            # Update other fields as needed

            item.save()
            return redirect('success')  # Redirect to a URL pattern named 'success'

    else:
        form = MemoForm()

    return render(request, 'report/input.html', {'items': items, 'form': form})
```

The above solutions should solve your issues and improve your form handling in Django.